# How to restrict findOne with policy

Tags: sails.js

With the **find** and **update** methods i am able to restrict fetching of data restricted to the logged in user by adding a policy that sets `req.options.where.owner = userID`, therefore i dont need to create custom controllers or models for these methods.

With **update** and **create** i can also set `req.options.values.owner = userID` so that the user cant create or update an object that will belong to another user.

But the problem is that the blueprint **findOne** controller does not have any options for this kind of filtering, so any logged in user can request an object created and owned by another user.

Is there anyway i can restrict **findOne** without writing my own controller and query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem, what you can do is to override the default blueprint action by creating a folder named **blueprints** in your api folder, there you can create a **findone.js** (lowercase) file,

1. copy the original blueprint action from `/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/findOne.js` to `/api/blueprints/findone.js`
2. add `.where( actionUtil.parseCriteria(req) );` to the query.
3. Dont forget to change the path of `actionutil` from `require('../actionUtil');` to `require('../../node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil');`

Voila, now the findOne action will respect your `req.options.where` queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify blueprint in your policies like this

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

  var blueprint = req.options.action;

  if (blueprint === 'findOne') {
    // do restriction here
    return next();
  }

  res.forbidden('not allowed to do something');
};
```

I'm rather forget, is blueprint name `findOne` or `findone`.